# Using Two Different Class In Each Other As Dependency Is Bad Practice?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What would happened if we use two different class in each other as a dependency. Does it cause any crucial issue like memory leak ? Or any annoying problem..

For example

```php
class Application {
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}

class Container {
    private $app;

    public function setApp(Application $application)
    {
        $this->app = $application;
    }
}
```

As I know objects passes by reference, each object above allocates certain amount on memory. But I'm not sure if it cause any other issue..

I know the question sounds silly but I would like to know your opinions and advices.

Comment: It's totally fine, but I am not sure how you plan to construct it.

Comment: @AlexBarker I think that's kinda impossible. I need to make setter for one of those.Sorry I was not focused that when I asking the question

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks aren't really an issue. Modern garbage collectors--the tools that look for memory that can be recycled--look for what are called "circular references", i.e. where one object references another and vice versa. PHP's garbage collector will detect that this circular reference exists, and as long as no outside reference is pointing to the `Application` or `Container` instance, the garbage collection will recycle the allocated memory as expected.

Furthermore, memory leaks are only really a problem when memory is not de-allocated. When a PHP process ends, that memory is de-allocated whether or not garbage collection has occurred. Given that PHP has a maximum runtime, you shouldn't be running into memory leaks in PHP unless you're doing something incredibly weird.